# Internet Explorer: Mixed Content Delivery Warning

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom, ssl, https

The following javascript is causing Internet Explorer to give a "Mixed Content" warning:

```
function init() {
  // quit if this function has already been called
  if (arguments.callee.done) return;

  // flag this function so we don't do the same thing twice
  arguments.callee.done = true;

  // kill the timer
  if (_timer) clearInterval(_timer);

  // do stuff
};

/* for Mozilla/Opera9 */
if (document.addEventListener) {
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init, false);
}

/* for Internet Explorer */
/*@cc_on @*/
/*@if (@_win32)
  document.write("<script id=__ie_onload defer src=javascript:void(0)><\/script>");
  var script = document.getElementById("__ie_onload");
  script.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == "complete") {
      init(); // call the onload handler
    }
  };
/*@end @*/

/* for Safari */
if (/WebKit/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) { // sniff
  var _timer = setInterval(function() {
    if (/loaded|complete/.test(document.readyState)) {
      init(); // call the onload handler
    }
  }, 10);
}

/* for other browsers */
window.onload = init;
```

It is used to detect when the DOM has completed loading.  What in this script would be causing a mixed content warning?

Comment: The reason for it is discussed at http://dean.edwards.name/weblog/2006/06/again/ (where this code comes from)

Comment: I agree with Cresent. This is similar to creating an about:blank IFRAME on a page delivered over https. The src has to reference something on https to be secure.

Comment: Why would you even use that sort of hack in this day and age?

Comment: I am using the Magento GO hosted solution, and uploading the jQuery library causes the functionality of Magento's template to stop working (much of the ui interactivity/etc.)  Is there a better way to check if the DOM has loaded with jQuery using a different method?

Comment: Solved - for anyone attempting to use the jQuery library within a Magento GO template, you must call jQuery.noConflict() at the end of the jQuery library.  Calling it within a later js file won't do the trick :)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is it's the creation of a script tag that is not using HTTPS.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but I don't think that IE insists that scripts, stylesheets, and images all be "https" when the main page is. It does so insist for `<iframe>` sources, however.

Comment: IE (and all other browsers) does require all scripts, stylesheets, images, and iframes to be https if the page being loaded is https.